# Java SHA256withRSA digital signature for String with decimal values

Tags: java, json, double, digital-signature

I have  to get as input  a json payload and  sign it with SHA256withRSA .
I'm trying to convert the json to java object , first when the value has an Integer type, the signature was correct but when I changed the type to Double as it is an amount , the generated signature string become wrong.

```
        byte[] b1 = Base64.getDecoder().decode(realPK);
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(b1);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
 
        Signature privateSignature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        privateSignature.initSign(kf.generatePrivate(spec));
        privateSignature.update(input.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        byte[] s = privateSignature.sign();
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(s);
    }
```

**Java Object**

`public class EmloyeeRecord {`

`......`

`@NotNull(message = "BasicSalary should not be empty")`
`@JsonProperty("BasicSalary")`
`public Double basicSalary;`
`...`
`}`

**Json Payload**

`"FileRecordRq": [`
`{`
`....`
`"BasicSalary": 378880.00,`
`....`
`}`

Comment: Not sure what's going on here, but experience tells me it could possibly be a problem of inherent floating point imprecision. Try using `BigDecimal` instead. If it doesn't work, you'll have taken a step that probably would be good to take anyway ;) n.b. always construct `BigDecimal` with a `String`